# Corda: What is the difference between Off-ledger and on-ledger data

Tags: blockchain, corda

After going through the Vault documentation of Corda, it is still not clear between how on-ledger & off-ledger data works in a Vault. A good explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. On-ledger data is states that resulted from Corda transactions; the notary attests that the transaction inputs haven't been used before, and registers the transaction outputs as unconsumed states. The on-ledger data is cryptographically secured, any tampering with the node's tables will lead to a faulty ledger. All states are final and cannot be updated or modified. Every transaction has a set of required signers; so there's always an audit trail showing who approved the transaction and when.
2. Off-ledger data is data that is not tracked by your distributed ledger; meaning it's not finalized by the notary or cryptographically secured; but there's nothing stopping you from using the node's database schema to add your own tables, and you can even insert data into those tables from inside of your flows, but that data is not protected; it's like the data of any non-blockchain related app, anyone with database access can change the data and there's no audit trail showing that the data was tampered with, or by who.

Have a look at my article [here](https://blog.b9lab.com/complementing-tokens-sdk-with-custom-reporting-e50df796a52d), it shows an example of on-ledger and off-ledger data; the on-ledger data is the tokens (e.g. `FungibleToken` states) which result from using the Tokens SDK flows (issue and move tokens); while the custom table that I created for reporting purposes is the off-ledger data, even though I insert data into it from inside of my flows; that data is not the result of a transaction that is finalized by the notary and signed by a quorum of parties, so anyone can login to the database and modify it.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example article on off-ledger/on-ledger data.